# Angular 2 yield reserved word

Tags: angular, typescript, yield-keyword

I want to use some generator in my A2 methods but it throws to me an error about: **reserved word in strict mode**. (the issue is in the **yield** statement).

How can I use generators in ng2? Thanks for any help!

My code looks like that:

```
  private sendSeries(socketInst) {

    function* generateSequenceMsg() {
      yield 1;
      yield 2;
      yield 3;
      yield 4;
    }

    let gen = generateSequenceMsg();

    setTimeout(() => {socketInst.send(`Message ${gen.next().value}`)}, 1000);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with TypeScript 1.8, emitted modules are always in strict mode.

If you want to use non-strict mode, then you need to add `noImplicitUseStrict : true` to your typescript compiler option.

Link to [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)